# How to call a static subclass method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

How can I call a static method of a subclass from a static method of the parent class?

```
class A {

  static foo(){
    // call subclass static method bar()
  }
}

class B extends A {

  static bar(){
    // do something
  }
}

B.foo()
```

**Update**:

The reason why I tried this is that subclasses of A would have worked best as singletons in my context and I wanted to use the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) in A.

<s>Since it looks like I cannot get a reference to a subclass from a static context</s> I am now exporting instances of subclasses of A which works just as well. Thanks.

**Update 2**

Yes, it is a duplicate to a degree (the other question does not involve  subclassing). The reference, even from a static context, is `this`. So this works:

```
static foo(){
    this.bar();
}
```

Comment: I believe you have javascript a bit confused, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Could @You point at a particular section, please?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You haven't declared anything in the base class from the sub class. So the call `B.foo()` won't return anything.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `this.bar()` - but notice that `A.foo()` won't work unless `A` has a  `foo` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused to your need, as it seems you sorta already get what you need to do with B.foo(). So, is this what you need?

```
class A {

  static foo(){
    // call subclass static method bar()
    // Because it is "static" you reference it by just calling it via
    // the class w/o instantiating it.
    B.bar() 

  }
}

class B extends A {

  static bar(){
    // do something
    console.log("I am a static method being called")
  }
}

// because "foo" is static you can call it directly off of 
// the class, like you are doing
B.foo()

// or
var D = new B()
D.bar() // won't work ERROR
A.foo() // Works <-- Is this is specifically what you are asking? Or 
        // calling it in the Super class like B.bar(), that is done in static method foo?
```

Is this what you are asking? If this does not answer your question, please let me know what I am misunderstanding and I'll try to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @james. Rather than calling `B.bar()` explicitly I would have liked to call something like `subClassRef.bar()` as `A` can have different subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

It makes the template pattern somewhat less elegant, but you can accomplish this via `super` in the subclass, eg:

```
class A {
  static foo() {
    this.bar()
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static foo() {
    super.foo()
  }
  static bar() {
    console.log("Hello from B")
  }
}

B.foo()
```